# Create TcpListener from HttpListener

Tags: c#, networking, websocket

I have created my own websocket class that extends the abstract System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket Class. my class uses TcpListener and TcpClient to communicate. After this server receives an HTTP-Get-formatted request that asks to upgrade to a websocket connection, I am able to complete the handshake successfully and communicate with a websocket client.

Separately I have a simple HTTP server that sends and receives HTTP requests using HttpListener and HTTPClient.

Now I want to combine them.

I would like this HTTP server to, upon receiving a websocket request, transfer the "connection" to my websocket server to handle. However I am struggling to conceptually understand what a TCP "connection" is.

I know that I can create a TCPClient using an existing socket, but I am unsure how to retrieve the existing HTTPListener's socket (maybe it can't be exposed?). And for that matter I am unsure what would happen if I tried to have a TCPClient and HTTPListener sharing the same socket.

So how do I construct a TCPListener from an existing HTTPListener?

Comment: [The HttpListener class is built on top of HTTP.sys, which is the kernel mode listener that handles all HTTP traffic for Windows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?msclkid=2e614c4ebe3e11ec896851b519ef8c09&view=net-6.0#httpsys)

Answer (score 1):

> However I am struggling to conceptually understand what a TCP
> "connection" is.

*[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html)* (and the subsequent RFCs that update it) is the standard for TCP. It explains what a TCP connection is, and later goes into more detail:

> Multiplexing:
>
> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
> communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
> addresses or ports within each host. Concatenated with the network and
> host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
> socket. ***A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection.***
> That is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections.
>
> The binding of ports to processes is handled independently by each
> Host. However, it proves useful to attach frequently used processes
> (e.g., a "logger" or timesharing service) to fixed sockets which are
> made known to the public. These services can then be accessed through
> the known addresses. Establishing and learning the port addresses of
> other processes may involve more dynamic mechanisms.
>
> Connections:
>
> The reliability and flow control mechanisms described above require
> that TCPs initialize and maintain certain status information for each
> data stream. ***The combination of this information, including
> sockets, sequence numbers, and window sizes, is called a
> connection.*** Each connection is uniquely specified by a pair of
> sockets identifying its two sides.
>
> When two processes wish to communicate, their TCP's must first
> establish a connection (initialize the status information on each
> side). When their communication is complete, the connection is
> terminated or closed to free the resources for other uses.
>
> Since connections must be established between unreliable hosts and
> over the unreliable internet communication system, a handshake
> mechanism with clock-based sequence numbers is used to avoid erroneous
> initialization of connections.